# Pandas set values for part of column with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm sure that there is a simple way to do this, but I can't seem to find it.
Essentially, I have a `DataFrame` with a `MultiIndex` and I want to set one part of a column (corresponding to a value in the first index level) with a `Series`. However, whatever I try, the values are being set to `NaN`, even though the index names align.

An example of the things I tried:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3),
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((('a1', 'a2'), ('b1', 'b2')),
                                                   names=['idx1', 'idx2']))
s = pd.Series([100, 101], index=['b1', 'b2'], name='col3')
df.loc['a1', 'col3'] = s
```

After this, I would expect `df` to be

```
           col1  col2  col3
idx1 idx2                  
a1   b1       0     1   100
     b2       3     4   101
a2   b1       6     7     8
     b2       9    10    11
```

but it is

```
           col1  col2  col3
idx1 idx2                  
a1   b1       0     1   NaN
     b2       3     4   NaN
a2   b1       6     7   8.0
     b2       9    10  11.0
```

Any idea on how to achieve this *without* `.to_numpy()` or `.to_list()` (since then I would need to check the order of items manually) in a one liner without doing something ridiculous like

```py
df.loc['a1', 'col3'] = s.to_frame().eval('idx1 = "a1"').reset_index().set_index(['idx1', 'idx2'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have in s values that are not present in df's Index, you could do:

```
df.loc[('a1', s.index), 'col3'] = s.values
```

This will work independently of the order of s

output:

```
           col1  col2  col3
idx1 idx2                  
a1   b1       0     1   100
     b2       3     4   101
a2   b1       6     7     8
     b2       9    10    11
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `s.to_numpy()` or `s.tolist()`:

```
>>> df.loc['a1', 'col3'] = s.to_numpy()
           col1  col2   col3
idx1 idx1                   
a1   b1       0     1  100.0
     b2       3     4  101.0
a2   b1       6     7    8.0
     b2       9    10   11.0
```

Comment: in theory yes, but this would not check for the order of the index, whereas assigning a `Series` would

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.loc['a1', 'col3'] = [100, 101]
```

Output:

[image]

Based on your comment:

```
s = pd.Series([100, 101], index=['b1', 'b2'], name='col3')
s = s.to_list()
df.loc['a1', 'col3'] = s
```

With the same output.

Based on the other comment!:

```
s = pd.Series([100, 101], index=(('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'b2')), name='col3')
df.loc['a1', 'col3'] = s
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: but I could not do this when the series comes from another `DataFrame`

Comment: So just use to_list() beforehand. Edited the answer.

Comment: then I would need to check the order of items manually (see comment to [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71529730/8106901)). I should have made that explicit in the question, edited now.

Comment: Look at the answer again.

Comment: then I'd need to change the index of the `Series`, which would be cumbersome if it comes from another `DataFrame` (look at last paragraph of question).

Comment: how would one do this for values of `idx2`?

Comment: Use df.loc[('a1', 'b1'), 'col3'] = 50.